# How to keep ids when loading SVG with @svgr/webpack?

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, svgo

I am loading SVG files with [@svgr/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack) into React, I works fine but it strips the ids of the elements.
In order to keep the ids, I saw the option `cleanIDs` in SVGO config file, which I set to false, but to no avail.
How can I keep my ids?

Here is how I configure the loader in webpacks:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "@svgr/webpack",
      options: {
        cleanIDs: false,
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

I also tried:

- to disable SVGO altogether, but then it fails to load the SVG files
- with option cleanupIDs, but the ids are still removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This config worked for me on `@svgr/webpack@5.5.0`:

```
use: [
  {
    loader: "@svgr/webpack",
    options: {
      svgoConfig: {
        plugins: [
          {
            cleanupIDs: false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Some links that helped me figure this out:

- [svgo webpack example](https://github.com/svg/svgo/blob/07ca9764f71fb946adc23f4ea9f19070d335305d/examples/test.js)
- [svgo config options](https://gist.github.com/pladaria/69321af86ce165c2c1fc1c718b098dd0)

Comment: Thank you @heidi, it works. However it has two new issues: it prevents collapsing groups, and the id is prefixed with the file name: from "path1" to "hexa_svg__path1". Do you notice the same?

Comment: I have the same issue with prefixed ID, which makes svg not work properly

Comment: @LouisCoulet Add `{prefixIds: false}` to `plugins` and you will be good to go. The doc says already disabled by default but you still need to disable it in this case https://github.com/svg/svgo#built-in-plugins